# Is it possible to have two different sbt versions for a project simultaneously

Tags: scala, sbt

I'm using an unsupported plugin that requires a pretty old sbt version (without autoplugin) for some tasks. Other tasks require plugins that relays on autoplugin. Older plugin works with 13.1 version and newer plugins work with latest stable releases.

Could I somehow use two different sbt interchangeably?

Comment: Are they both versions in the 0.13.x cycle (say for example 0.13.2 and 0.13.9) or is the old plugin for 0.12.x? If the old plugin is public, could you provide a link to it?

Comment: 13.1 and 13.9. Added to the question

Answer (score 1):

sbt is backwards binary compatible across minor versions. So concretely, sbt 0.13.9 is backwards binary compatible with 0.13.1 (but not with 0.12.x). This means that sbt 0.13.9 is perfectly capable of using an sbt plugin that was built for 0.13.1.

So you don't need your project to have "two different sbt versions". You only use 0.13.9, and you use all the plugins you want, including that built for 0.13.1. There is nothing special to do.

Comment: The plugin in question uses reflection and access to internal sbt API, so no backward compatibility to it.

Comment: Have you tried? What kind of error do you get? Anyway, then that plugin is really playing with fire, and that would make me wary of using it. If it doesn't "just work", then you should seriously consider a) find a replacement or b) take over its maintenance and update it for more recent versions of sbt.

Comment: It would be easier to do some shell magic to provide two sbt scripts with different versions and different project definitions